# Highchart / Use global option into an external JS file

Tags: javascript, highcharts, external

I want to put dynamic information into my php page and keep my global option to an external JS files but "option" seem undefined:

**External file:**

```
$(function () {

var options = {
        chart: {
            rendedTo: 'barchart',
            type: 'column',
            width: 765
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Nombre de sous-titres postés ce mois'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = (this.y > 1) ? 's' : '';
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                     this.y+' sous-titre'+s+' posté'+s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Nombre d\'upload'
        }]
    }
});
```

Then I put the building lines on my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('include/ajax/statistiquesMembreMensuel.json.php?id=1', function(data) {
            options.xAxis.categories = data[0];
            options.series[0].data = data[0];
            options.chart.title = "Nombre d\'upload mensuel effectués par le membre '.stripslashes($row['pseudo']).'";
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I need to put the how can I send the `$_GET['id']` information to the `getJSON` url if i put it into the .js file ?

How can I edit the chart title after the chart has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove `var` to create global variable, or better, remove `$(function () { ... });` which wraps `options`.

2) To set title, see [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle%28%29).

Comment: Thansks ! Remove `var` change every thing.

This is the final code :
`$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('include/ajax/statistiquesMembreMensuel.json.php?id=1', function(data) {
    options.xAxis.categories = data[0];
    options.series[0].data = data[1];
    var chart = $('#barchart').highcharts(options);
    $('#barchart').highcharts().setTitle({ text: "Nombre d'upload mensuel effectués par le membre Pseudo" });
   });
  });`